# Bases for a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

It is easily proved that these vectors are li, on the other hand I am trying to prove that $gen\{(x_{\alpha\not= \beta}),a\}=E$, my idea is to use the hypothesis to write x as a linear combination of the vectors of the base of the hypothesis and to rewrite this linear combination to the terms of the proposed base but I can't get it

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $\hat{a} = a - \xi^\beta x_\beta$.  Note that $\hat{a} \in \mathrm{span}(\{x_\alpha: \alpha \neq \beta\})$.  Then $\frac{1}{\xi^\beta}(a - \hat{a}) = x_\beta$, so $x_\beta \in \mathrm{span}(\{x_\alpha: \alpha \neq \beta \} \cup \{a\})$.  Then \begin{align}
\mathrm{span}(\{x_\alpha: \alpha \neq \beta \} \cup \{a\}) &= \mathrm{span}(\{x_\alpha: \alpha \neq \beta \} \cup \{a, x_\beta \})  \\
    &= \mathrm{span}(\{x_\alpha: \alpha \neq \beta \} \cup \{x_\beta \})  \\
    &= E  \text{.}
\end{align}